# Teach iOS SFSpeechRecognizer custom words (medication names, chemistry terms, etc)

Tags: ios, dictionary, speech-to-text, sirikit, sfspeechrecognizer

I have a question regarding the integration of the speech to text iOS library called SFSpeechRecognizer.
I need SFSpeechRecognizer to recognize terms that are not present in the iOS dictionary like medication names, chemistry terms, etc.
I would have to add them, somehow, for SFSpeechRecognizer to be able to recognise them.
Is this possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add your words to the

SFSpeechRecognitionRequest.contextualStrings array:

```
 let request = SFSpeechURLRecognitionRequest(url: fileUrl)
 request.contextualStrings = ["twersht", "baglom"]
```

now "My baglom is very twersht" will be returned by the SFSpeechRecognizer after you say it.

[contextualStrings reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/speech/sfspeechrecognitionrequest/1649391-contextualstrings/)